# How to pass the SERVER_PROTOCOL in an Apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, http2

I have an Apache reverse proxy that handles HTTP/2 in front of an application that only handles HTTP/1.1.

I would like to pass the actual HTTP version back to the application. I have tried using

```
RequestHeader set X-Server-Proto "%{SERVER_PROTOCOL}e"
```

but the backend application is getting an empty value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I can use a different variable

```
RequestHeader set X-HTTP2 "%{HTTP2}e"
```